# A Generic error occured in GDI + while saving image in console application using c# with memory stream

Tags: c#, image, save

I am getting error mentioned below when I am trying to save image using memorystream in c#.  The Error is only thrown when Byte array byteImageData length equals 24000, otherwise code is working fine. Below is the code snippet:

```
string strDbConn = string.Empty;
string strImageFileName = string.Empty;
string strImageData = string.Empty;
DataSet imageDS = new DataSet();
Byte[] byteImageData = new Byte[0];
Image saveImage;
string strImgSavePath = string.Empty;
try
{
    //---open the database connection
    strDbConn = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBConnection"].ToString().Trim();
    SqlConnection dbcon = new SqlConnection(strDbConn);
    dbcon.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter imageSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from image_data", dbcon);
    imageSqlDataAdapter.Fill(imageDS);
    dbcon.Close();
    for (int i = 0; i < imageDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        strImageFileName = imageDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"].ToString().Trim();
        strImageData = imageDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["signature_vod__c"].ToString().Trim();
        //converting string to byte array
        byteImageData = Convert.FromBase64String(strImageData);
        //---create Memory stremm from the Image Byte data
        MemoryStream stmImageData = new MemoryStream(byteImageData);
        //--saving the image
        saveImage = Image.FromStream(stmImageData);
        strImgSavePath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ImageSavePath"].ToString().Trim();
        saveImage.Save(strImgSavePath + strImageFileName + ".jpeg"); // error comes here
        //stmImageData.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

The error that is thrown is:

```
Messgae = A generic error occurred in GDI+. 
Inner Exception = null
```

Stack Trace:

```
at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename)
   at VeevaImageApp.Program.CreateAndSaveImageusingDataSet2() in Program.cs:line 141
```

Error is coming only when Byte array byteImageData length is 24000 else code works file - what could be the issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: are you sure the image data is correct? If you save the binary data to a file named test.jpeg does it render OK?

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the location you're trying to save to?  http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2009/02/28/solving-quot-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-quot-exception.aspx

Comment: In DataSet I am having 5000 images it works file till 509 images and after that when I get 510th image byte array length reaches 24000 and it gives me error that time

Comment: yeah I have permission to write to location, code is able to write 509 images but error comes when byteImageData length is 24000

Comment: Instead of declaring `byteImageData` before the loop, have you tried using an implicit declaration when you convert `strImageData`, like `var byteImageData = Convert.FromBase64String(strImageData);` ?

Comment: Hi AJ  I tried that also but still it throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

What format is the image data in? If it is already JPG, you should just use `File.WriteAllBytes(path, byteImageData)`. If you truly need a conversion, you should use the newer image encoder/decoder classes: search the web for info on JpegBitmapEncoder or PngBitmapEncoder. (If these are photos or scans us JPEG, otherwise use PNG.)